# Xcode - UITableView Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I've met some kind of a problem when selecting a row.

Basically, whenever the user selects a row within the UITableViewController I want certain content to be displayed, predominantly text. I do have this working, to a degree. By using the following code:

```
var varView = Int()
if (varView == 0){

    Label.text = "E110"

}

else {
    if (varView == 1){
    Label.text = "Veyron"

     }

    else {
        Label.text = "Error"
    }

}
```

This does work as mentioned. However, due to the fact I have headers to categorise products within my UITableViewController, it appears to "refresh" after each section header.

I have used arrays to populate my UITableViewController with both section headers and text to populate the UITableVC like so

```
struct Brands {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionBrands : [String]!
}

var brandArray = [Brands]()


override func viewDidLoad() {


    brandArray = [


    Brands(sectionName: "Bugatti", sectionBrands: ["EB 110","Veyron"]),

    Brands(sectionName: "Cadillac", sectionBrands: ["Biarritz","BLS", "CTS", "Escalade", "SRX", "STS"]),
```

I have a LOT more than that! Haha.

However, due to the fact I have two rows under Buggati the Change Content Code works,but when selecting the first row under Cadillac, I get a return type of "E110", when selecting "BLS" I get a return of "Veyron" and every other row returns a value of "Error". I expected anything after the first to rows will return with "Error" but it appears to be "refreshing" the int count as mentioned.

This is the code I am using to return the value(s) which I desired depending on which row is selected:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!


    DestVC.varView  = indexPath.row
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on how to resolve this matter? Or even use the name of the field to determine what is displayed as opposed to using an Integer?

Thank you.

P.S- I am using `SWRevealViewController`, which I don't think matters, but I believe it's worth mentioning.

Comment: do you want the selected row to open in a new view?

Comment: When a row is selected another view controller is used as a segue. But as mentioned, the error lies within the code I believe. I have re-used the cell identifier, could this possibly be a problem?

Comment: can't help it I'm also a beginner like you but i can suggest you how to open a selected item form tableViewController into a new viewController using navigation or without NavagationViewContoller.

Comment: Good idea, however, due to the fact I have 500+ entries within my array the size of the application would be quite large and in essence, isn't very practical. However, I appreciate the reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

For TableViewController Add this Function to your ViewController.m   make sure you have both methods define properly in your View Controller.

1. tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
2. tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

   than:-

   ```
   (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewdidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   NSArray *keys=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"CellNumberOne",@"CellNumbertwo",@"CellNumberThree",@"CellNumberFour", nil];
   NSArray *objects=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];


   self.myData=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

   NSArray *keys=[self.myData allKeys];

   NSString *cellName=[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *detail=[self.myData valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if (cellName==@"CellNumberOne") {
       UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *view=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CellNumberOne"]; //you have to set identifier for all the view controllers
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
      }
    if (cellName==@"CellNumbertwo") {
       UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *view=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CellNumberTwo"]; //you have to set identifier for all the view controllers
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
     }


    if (cellName==@"CellNumberThree") {
       UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *view=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CellNumberThree"]; //you have to set identifier for all the view controllers
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
      }


    if (cellName==@"CellNumberFour") {
       UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *view=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CellNumberFour"]; //you have to set identifier for all the view controllers
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
     }



   }
   ```